# Did Jar Jar Binks ever meet Anakin Skywalker (Darth Vader) again?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

After watching *Robot Chicken*'s [humorous skit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdS2kCUGvfo), I'm very curious to know if any information exists regarding whether or not everyone's favorite *Star Wars* character actually found out about Anakin Skywalker's reincarnation as Vader or interacts with him at all after *Revenge of the Sith*?

Comment: @phantom42, Oh wow, didn't see that. And I was looking! Lol. Well, let me change it from "What happened to Binks" (since we already know the answer) to "Did Binks and Anakin ever meet again?"

Comment: What did @phantom42 say? I don't know why he deleted the comment.

Comment: Is it possible experiencing Jar Jar was part of what lead Anakin to the dark side?

Comment: As you can see, he drowned, then exploded; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLACxMXBRhM

Comment: @SachinShekhar, Initially, my question was "What was the fate of Binks?" But phantom commented that it was a duplicate, so I changed it.

Comment: Woah. Spoilers in the title!

Comment: As a matter of fact, they DID later meet and became great friends again. In fact, Binks is the genetic template for the Original Trilogy's stormtroopers.

Comment: @Omegacron, That makes sense considering their aiming skills.

Comment: It's certainly *possible* that they met but it didn't happen in any of the currently recognised "canon" properties (e.g. the 6 films and their novelisations, the Clone Wars TV series or the Clone Wars film), nor has it happened in any of the "legends" properties (e.g. the EU novels or comics).

Comment: @Richard, Good, now let's turn that into an answer and end this. XD

Comment: @PartyKingThrandeezy - I refuse to turn my ignorance into an answer. You just know that 30 seconds after I post it, someone will find a picture of them passing in a hallway at the Senate building.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Has it happened in any *canon* media? Hell no.**

It hasn't happened in any of the properties that are recognised by LucasFilm as [canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon) properties (i.e. the 6 feature films, Clone Wars film, Clone Wars TV series, Rebels TV series), nor has it happened in any of properties that have been reclassified as "[legends](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Legends)" properties (i.e. the Ewoks films, Xmas Holiday Special, Radio plays, EU novels, comics, etc).

**Has it happened in any *licensed* media? Yes.**

As far as I can tell, the only places they've crossed paths again are in satirical works such as [Robot Chicken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdS2kCUGvfo) and [Lego Star Wars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrCopwR064s) where the two are put together for comedy effect.

**Is it *theoretically* possible that they came into contact again? Yes.

Is it *likely* that they came into contact again? No.**

As described in this answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/what-did-the-general-public-know-about-darth-vader/36831#36831), the general public were probably unaware of Vader's presence and it's unlikely that he was regularly frequenting the Senate Chambers on Coruscant. Those books that do describe his dealings refer to his having a [private palace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader%27s_Palace) near to the Emperor's offices with shielded corridors and its own landing platform. His guests are invariably Imperial spies, bounty hunters and Naval officers rather than Senators and politicians.

Comment: Just want to say, that Robot Chicken segment is exactly my nightmare.

Comment: @Thebluefish - My nightmare is that they'll come up with a binks-like character to put in the new trilogy.

Comment: Please don't say these things! Oh I sincerely hope they don't do that D: