Why is Darth Vader almost never addressed as "Darth Vader"?
In continuation to Why was Darth Vader called Lord Vader? and The use of 'Darth' as Vader's name, not title, in Star Wars I ask why in almost all instances (mainly the films) Vader is always addressed as "Lord Vader" and almost never as "Darth Vader"? Princess Leia called him "Darth Vader" once (Episode 4: New Hope, when he arrests her at the beginning of the movie), and so did Obi-Wan Kenobi (Episode 4: New Hope, the duel aboard the Death Star). While it is well understood why he is called "Lord" (as a title or rank of authority), the question is why the title "Darth" is almost never used.
Clarification: I meant he would be addressed as "Darth Vader" instead of "Lord Vader", especially by the Emperor.

Because calling your incredibly scary boss by his first "name" is career limiting!

@Paulie_D And windpipe-limiting, if he's in the wrong mood.

He's a Sith Lord

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9911/what-did-the-general-public-know-about-darth-vader

I wager they simply didn't know. Why would they tell people he's a Sith and what Darth even means? While some people surly knew, it was at least semi-secret, I think. Lord, on the other hand, is neutral by itself.

At least from a 1980s perspective...Vader is known to the Galaxy as the last surviving Jedi that was loyal to the legitimate leader of the Republic now Empire. It is just a vicious rumor that his first name was Darth and an even worse rumor that the Emperor himself has any force abilities.

I don't recall it being specifically spelled out in canon (or most of legends for that matter), but Darth is his rank.
Just as you wouldn't address Duke Vader as Duke Vader, you address him by the honorific his title deserves. In this case, it would be, "Lord."
OOU it's entirely down to the fact that Vader had to be seen as being terrifying to his own side, so even Palpatine was compelled to address him respectfully to heighten that fear.

I mean, OOU it's because "Darth" was originally just his first name. Obi-Wan tells Luke about "a young Jedi named Darth Vader," and calls him "Darth" later like it's his name. It does still work well enough as rank vs. title thing though.

@MiloP Well, yes. There's also that. And Lucas not knowing that he gave the whole game away to the Netherlands before he'd even decided what the game was (Vader is Dutch for "Father", something that Lucas hadn't even come up with he decided on the name).

Also, there are instances where someone in Star Wars is addressed by their rank. Count Dooku being an obvious one. Who would also be addressed as, "My Lord." But Dooku apparently wasn't scary enough.

@GeoffAtkins That's a myth though. Vader wasn't meant to be Luke's father until Empire. Lucas didn't mean to call him "Dark Father" because he originally wasn't! Same as Leia wasn't Luke's sister in Star Wars.

I also disagree, people call Kings and Counts and even military ranks all the time. King Charles, "my Queen", General Solo, General Ackbar. I think Star Wars is inconsistent here, and so this isn't a good explanation.

@AndresF.: I think that was the point GeoffAtkins was making — “giving the game away … before he’d even decided what the game was”

@RLH you're right, I misread the comment.
